How can I edit the user registry for a child account on Windows 10?
I have a parent and child account on a Windows 10 box. I want to edit the child's registry to turn off the ability to make web searches from the start menu (I need to add a key to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows).
If I make that change from the parent account, I'm editing only the parent's values, not the child's.  The child account isn't able to run regedit.  When I try to open regedit "as administrator" and enter the parent login, HCU is loaded with the parent's registry, not the child's.
I figured the only option was to log into the parent account and use "Load Hive" to pull up the child account NTUSER.dat, but then I get the error "This file is in use", even though that account isn't running.
Is there any way to edit the registry for a non-admin child account?

The answer was embarrassingly simple, but I'll leave this up in case someone else runs into the same mental block:
Temporary change the child account to an admin account, log into the child account to use regedit, then change it back.

The alternative would have been to run Regedit “as Administrator” account then input your accounts username and password

I'm surprised that you are getting a "The file is in use" error. I load other account hives all the time using just the method that you mentioned. In fact, I recently wrote a script that automatically loads all user hives in order to change values simultaneously.
Try this: log into the child account, use "Switch User" to log into your admin account, and you should find the child hives already loaded into regedit under HKEY_USERS.
If that does not work for some reason, try the program LockHunter to determine whether some third-party program is locking NTUSER.dat.
